# Get JUST ROLESESSIONNAME for use in an iam policy placeholder variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In the context of an assumed role (in my case a role assumed by SAML logged in users) the `${aws:userid}` in an iam policy maps to `ROLEID:ROLESESSIONNAME`. That sucks because I cant plug that in for Resources which I was planning on naming after the ROLESESSIONNAME (like iam user accounts for example).

Can I separate ROLESESSIONNAME in a placeholder I can use in a Resource in a policy? I not talking about conditions, I want to do something like this:
`"Resource": ["arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-WITHOUT-HYPHENS:user/${aws:userID}"]`

Comment: It seems like one problem with this strategy is that the role session name doesn't uniquely identify anything by itself.

Comment: Im not sure i understand what do you mean. i understand why iam might need to append the role id to make it unique im just wondering if there is any way can parse that for the resource string.

Comment: What about [`saml:sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html#condition-keys-saml)?

Comment: whaaaa that works your amazing! yes saml:sub is 100% exactly what i was looking for. i had no idea I had access to so many saml specific vars, please mark that as an answer. btw does aws list ALL the placeholder vars anywhere in one place? Im always hunting for this in their docs

Comment: `saml:sub` did not work for me. In my case, `saml:sub` does not appear to match `RoleSessionName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also trying to use the `RoleSessionName` property to give access to a particular federated user, but it did not work. However,
I was successfully able to use the `saml:sub` attribute, for which I had to set the **`NameID`** format to email. This will set the subject of the SAML Assertion to user's email.

Now you can use the user's email to give access:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "saml:sub": "user@example.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My previous `NameID` format was `transient` which was not generating consistent `subject` attribute. You can use CloudTrail events to debug the SAML assertions which come into effect in AWS.

Also, your IAM Role needs to have the `sts:TagSession` action allowed under **Trust Relationships** which creates the `saml:*` tags / attributes for a session.

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html#condition-keys-saml